How to edit an invalid Custom Metadata ListView
Custom Metadata ListView allowed me to save a list view that was invalid. What made it invalid was putting 2 values in a RHS box - metadata queries do not support ORs like regular objects do.
When I use the Manage button or link now, the last one I used is invalid so an error displays.
I see no way that I can edit it to remove the error or to select a different list view as default. The error on clicking Manage Custom Metadata is
"An error has occurred in the following section: [Exception, DisjunctionsNotSupportedException]. Salesforce.com has been notified of this error."
I know I can't have an OR in the criteria so I need to remove it
I tried to delete the list view from WorkBench but it is not allowed there.
Is there a way to resolve this without using metadata API?

Open a support case with Salesforce.

I found a way to fix the broken list view.
I created a list view in a sandbox with the same name and deployed it with a change set. I hope this helps someone else. Fortunately, I had a backup of the metadata so I had access to the exact name of the list view.

good solution and thank you for contributing to the community's knowledge base.  You could have used workbench or the CLI or a devops tool like Gearset to retrieve the listview into a text file that you could edit, then deploy.  Under the covers, this is of course the MDAPI (but so are chnagesets)
